# Making database results as html links

Tags: view

I am new to cakephp and I want my database results to be shown as a link so that if a user clicks on the result, he/she should be redirected to a different page which is in different controller and have a different view. Any Help??

For example: I have this line of code that displays the result from the database.

```
    <?php echo $Menu['Menu'] ['menuname']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
```

I want the users to see this menuname as a link which will redirect to the menu items page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a plane php code (programming language). So, you can add any link to any page you want at the menu. For example replace this code with:

`<?php echo '<a href="/somepage.php">'.$Menu['Menu']['menuname']. '</a>''&nbsp;</td>`

Or post what exactly link you want to show for users.